# How to solve an integer programming optimization problem containing a combinatorics expression?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, integer-programming, linearization

I have this minimization problem

$\min \sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i {X_i\choose r}$

s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^kX_i=m$

and $0<X_i<N$, $\alpha_i>0$, $1<k<N$, $m=(k-1)N$, and $1<r<N$

where $N$, $m$, $r$, and $\alpha_i$ are constants. ($N$ is the number of nodes in the problem)

But I have no idea how to approach it. Any ideas will help greatly.

Comment: $\forall i, X_i > r$ ? Are there more bounds even relative ?

Comment: In practice, $X_i$ can be less than $r$. But then $X_i\choose r$ will be zero.

Comment: then it is a very general and complicate question ...

Comment: Typical size of problem, and typical value on r and m?

Comment: There is not a typical limit on these variables and they can become large. But I'll add some ranges in relation to other variables in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinatorics in integer programming, pretty cool...

You are facing a typical case of integer programming with a non-linear cost function. What you can do (like always in those cases), is to define

$ \forall i \in [1,k], \forall n \in [0,m], Y_{i,m} $ the binary variable equal to $1$ iff $X_i = n$.

Your problem then becomes

$\min \sum_{i \in [1,k]} \sum_{n \in [0,m]} \alpha_i \binom{n}{r} Y_{i,n} $

s.t. $ \sum_{i \in [1,k]} \sum_{n \in [0,m]} n \cdot Y_{i,n} = m $

$\forall i \in [1,k], \sum_{n \in [0,m]} Y_{i,n} = 1$

Which is linear

I hope for you that this trick doesn't make an  unsolvable MIP (I don't know the size of your problem). This kind of linearization trick is usually expensive computation-wise.

I sincerely wish you find a trick requiring less variables (for instance, if you are lucky enough so that $\binom{X_i}{r}$ is always convex, you don't need all of this). Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I still don't know if this will solve my problem but it gets me on the right path.